# Backend spec for Authentication (React Native App)

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, react-native, access-token

I have just started working with react native and the backend of my app is handled by another company. I have a very simple login/ register feature where  for register the user needs to enter the following fields (Name, Email, Password) . To login its just email and password. I am expecting a Json Token and the information like name in return.

I need to ask the backend company for this service but have never documented something like this. I Was wondering if anyone could direct me to some documentation of this flow that i could send to them

Comment: Are you asking how you make HTTP requests in React Native?

Comment: No i am asking for a api spec for login that i can implement in my react native app with the above requirement. I want to be sure i am using a good standard and best practice.  A sample request and response would help me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Is this the sort of flow you're looking for?

https://jwt.io/

It is a standard created by the company Auth0, which provides authentication-as-a-service.